# How can I use the Hetman authorisation in Realms of Arcania: Blade of Destiny

Tags: realms-of-arkania-blade-of-destiny

I have received the Hetman authorization, however I am not sure where I am supposed to use it to pick up the free weapons.  There doesn't seem to be an option to use it at Grollo's weapon shop.

Comment: Is this question about the original [Blade of Destiny (1992)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realms_of_Arkania:_Blade_of_Destiny) or the [2013 remake](http://store.steampowered.com/app/237550/Realms_of_Arkania_Blade_of_Destiny/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authorisation note is not used at the weapon shop, rather, there is another building called Armoury in Thorwal just down from the Hetman's compound where the note can be used.